# Is there a way to interact with the last logged object in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I use `console.log` to log an object from inside a script, I can see that object in the console, and I can inspect it by clicking the little arrows. So I can **see** what methods it has (even in its prototype). But is it possible for me to **run** one of those methods from right there in the console?

In other words, is there some kind of magic variable (similar to `$0`) that I can type into the console, which will get me the last logged object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually use `$_` to get the previously evaluated statement

```
$$   // Returns an array of elements that match the given CSS selector.
$0   // The currently-selected object in the inspector.
$_   // The previously evaluated statement
$1   // The previously-selected object in the inspector.
$n(index)    // Access to an array of last 5 inspected elements.
```

For a complete list of everything there is that you can use for all parts of chrome check out the cheatsheet. http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2):

There is no such magic variable for objects logged via console.log at the moment. Please file a feature request if you need one: http://webkit.org/new-inspector-bug